# How to add data from API call to tableviewcell in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am setting up a basic app that returns values from an API call to cells in a tableview. Various examples I've seen online configure the service file to decode directly from a model. However, I am trying to set up my service file so that it decodes from the ViewModel, if possible. When I run the app in Xcode I do not get errors, but I'm also seeing blank cells in my tableview. I am still fairly new to API calls in Swift. Any idea how I can configure this to return API call values to the cells while still using a viewModel? See my code below:

In my WebService file, I set up my URLSession as follows:

```
class WebService {
        
    func getStocks(completion: @escaping (([SymbolViewModel]?) -> Void)) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://island-bramble.glitch.me/stocks") else {
            fatalError("URL is not correct")
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            let symbols = try? JSONDecoder().decode([SymbolViewModel].self, from: data)
            symbols == nil ? completion(nil) : completion(symbols)

        }.resume()

    }
}
```

The ViewModel is set up like so:

```
struct SymbolViewModel:Decodable {
 
    let stockSymbol: Symbol
    
    var symbol: String {
        return self.stockSymbol.symbol.uppercased()
    }
    
    var price: String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", self.stockSymbol.price)
    }
}
```

The Model:

```
struct Symbol: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let price: Double
}
```

The ViewController with the TableView functions and TableViewCell:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let webService = WebService()
    var symbols = [SymbolViewModel]()
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
                
        webService.getStocks { symbols in
            if let symbols = symbols {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.symbols = symbols
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var mySymbol: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myPrice: UILabel!

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    /// tableView functions
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return symbols.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: TableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        
        cell.mySymbol.text = symbols[indexPath.row].symbol
        cell.myPrice.text = symbols[indexPath.row].price

        return cell
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "stockSymbol", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"stockSymbol\", intValue: nil) (\"stockSymbol\").", underlyingError: nil))
0 elements
```

Comment: If you put a print/breakpoint in the `self.symbols = symbols` inside DispatchQueue.. do you see data there? Do you see an array of symbols or something coming as a response from that api call as `symbols`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added a breakpoint on self.symbols = symbols and ran the app, but it doesn't seem to hit the breakpoint

Comment: There is a `DecodingError`. Don't `try?`, add a `do - catch` block  and `print(error)` in the `catch` clause.

Comment: most probably you might have an error with decoding, either the type you are trying to decode is not whats coming from backend or the naming is slightly different, as @vadian suggested, try to check the error

Comment: I added print(error) to the catch clause and got an error message. See ERROR MESSAGE in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is wrong.

First of all if you declare computed properties you have to add `CodingKeys` to prevent the computed properties from being decoded. This is the main reason of the error, however there are more.

The JSON is an array of (one-dimensional) dictionaries, the corresponding model is

```
struct StockSymbol : Decodable {
    
    let symbol : String
    let price : Double
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case symbol, price }
    
    var priceAsString: String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", price)
    }
}
```

The other struct `Symbol` is not needed.

Decode it

```
do {
    let symbols = try? JSONDecoder().decode([StockSymbol].self, from: data)
    completion(symbols)
} catch {
    print(error)
    completion(nil)
}
```

and you have to reload the table view inside the completion handler

```
webService.getStocks { symbols in
    if let symbols = symbols {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.symbols = symbols
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

---

A more sophicticated way is the `Result` type, it returns either the valid data or the error

```
class WebService {
    
    func getStocks(completion: @escaping (Result<[StockSymbol],Error>) -> Void) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://island-bramble.glitch.me/stocks") else {
            fatalError("URL is not correct")
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }
            completion( Result {try JSONDecoder().decode([StockSymbol].self, from: data!)})
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

and call it

```
webService.getStocks { [weak self]  result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let symbols):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.symbols = symbols
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .failure(let error): print(error) // or show the error to the user
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. All of that worked. @vadian does ```struct: StockSymbol``` constitute as a model or viewModel?

Comment: Practically there is no difference. `StockSymbol` is just the model.